# Redirect after Registration

Tags: laravel

I have a link of my application like `abc.com/jobs?9`. User will get this link thorough email. If user click on this link user will redirected to  `abc.com`. If user is unregistered then user will register on `abc.com`. After registration user will redirect to `abc.com/jobs?9`.

How can I do that ?

In my application after registration user is redirect to `Dashboard`.

Comment: Set a cookie or session variable, then use that value after registering the user.

Answer (score 1):

Here my code for to make a user go straight to a certain page after registration in the controller just change the redirect('') to the desired page route.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $formFields = $request->validate([
        'name' => ['required', 'min:3', 'max:255', Rule::unique('users', 'name')],
        'email' => ['required', 'email', Rule::unique('users', 'email')],
        'password' =>
        [
            'required', 'confirmed',
            // Password::min(8)
            //     ->max(255)
            //     ->mixedCase()
            //     ->letters()
            //     ->numbers()
            //     ->symbols()
            //     ->uncompromised(),
        ],
    ]);

    //Hash Password
    // $formFields['password'] = bcrypt($formFields['password']);

    // Create User
    $user = User::create($formFields);

    // Login
    auth()->login($user);

    return redirect('/')->with('message', 'User created and logged in');
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jasper Kenneth Samson. Should this code redirect to `abc.com/jobs?9` ? Thanks.

Comment: the redirect is thats in the route  Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('static.index');
  })->name('index'); so this redirects to my index is i want it to redirect to a specific PAGE like 
Route::get('/revenue-cycle-consulting', function () {
    return view('static.revenue-cycle-consulting');
  })->name('revenue-cycle-consulting');
Then i will change the return redirect('/revenue-cycle-consulting')